# Redux in React Native app is very slow with lots of data

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a large array of JSON objects I’m storing in a single Redux variable (~8k items, each with object about 1kb each for a total of 8mb). This seems to make Redux calls slow even for the most trivial actions and reducers that don’t actually do anything. For example, calling this `doNothing()` action and reducer produces a 500ms wait time on device without running on the debugger:

```js
// action
export const doNothing = () => {
  return {
    type: DO_NOTHING
  };
};

// reducer
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DO_NOTHING: {
      return state;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My best attempt to profile this issue is via `slowlog`, which is where I came up with the 500ms figure for the Redux call in my React component. For a smaller set of data (~500 items), I still get a wait, but it’s closer to 100ms. This is all on device and it gets slower on the simulator and the debugger. I'm testing this on a simple view with just a button to rule out complications from expensive re-selects and re-renders. A possible complication is that I'm using `redux-offline` which persists the Redux store to `AsyncStorage`, however I get identically poor performance when I turn off persistence.

Ideally I address the bottleneck directly, but I’m also open to workarounds. I tried wrapping the action calls in `setTimeout`, but that just seems to delay the slowdown in my React Native app.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I have no experience with this but am curious if calls are slow to all variables, or only the 8mb variable?

Comment: Is this equally slow in development and production? I also see performance issues on the simulator (less than 500ms, but still noticeable), but in production everything is fine. Another thing: I noticed that dispatching actions during animations also tends to decrease performance.

Comment: We use a similar library called: `redux-persist`.. and we saw similar slowness with our app, with much smaller data. The problem with redux-persist was that it read the new incoming state (even if it's same), did a diff and wrote the updated state (even if nothing changed), to the async storage. Our solution was to normalize the large data into separate reducer states. Also, if this state is static and doesn't need to be shared, i would just store it into a JSON file to avoid writes in reducer states.

Comment: I have a similar situation - I'm implementing an offline mode currently, so im persisting everything on the device. I don't think it is an unreasonable amount tho. I have an array of 2500 small objects, 0.2mb according to response header. 
The bizzare thing is that it runs beautifully in debug build, whilst release build takes 15 seconds to react to any button press!!!
And i know it is the data as I have tested with no change other than filtering half of it before passing to redux and it runs fine.Totally at my whits end with this!

Answer (score 2):

Storing a large array of data in the redux state which indirectly gets stored in RAM is not a reliable way.

The best practice would be to use a local database so that it will store data in storage memory.

For ReactNative there is a popular database `Watermelon DB` that fits this kind of scenario

Do check out it's documentation : https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/

Here is what it solves

> For simple apps, using Redux or MobX with a persistence adapter is the easiest way to go. But when you start scaling to thousands or tens of thousands of database records, your app will now be slow to launch (especially on slower Android devices). Loading a full database into JavaScript is expensive!

> Watermelon fixes it by being lazy. Nothing is loaded until it's requested. And since all querying is performed directly on the rock-solid SQLite database on a separate native thread, most queries resolve in an instant.

Use Watermelon DB to store/retrieve large data

And meanwhile, use the redux state for storing only small data.

Hope this helps